# How to convert a C++ program that uses CUDA into MEX

Tags: c++, matlab, cuda

For work, I am converting the Image Denoising program that comes with the CUDA SDK into a MATLAB program. As far as I know, I have made all the necessary changes required by MATLAB, but when I try to call mex on it, MATLAB returns a bunch of linkage errors that I have no idea how to fix. If anyone has any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

The command I am giving MATLAB is:

`mex imageDenoisingGL.cpp -I..\..\common\inc -IC:\CUDA\include -L..\..\common\lib -lglut32`

And the output from MATLAB is a bunch of these:

```
imageDenoisingGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__cutCheckCmdLineFlag@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl __cutilExit(int,char * *)" (?__cutilExit@@YAXHPAPAD@Z)
```

I am running:
Windows XP x32
Visual Studio 2005
MATLAB 2007a

Comment: I generally find it easier to compile MEX files without MATLAB.  I mean just use Visual Studio; a MEX file is, after all, just a DLL with a funny name.  That way I avoid problems arising from bad mexopts and the like.

Comment: Another practice I have adopted, and I haven't a clue whether it is a best or worst practice, is to do no computation in the routine called 'mexfunction' (or whatever it is called in C++, I write in Fortran).  The mex function is just a wrapper to marshal Matlab arguments and call a C++ (or, in my case, Fortran) subroutine / function.  In your context I wouldn't make calls to CUDA functions from the mex function itself, but from one of the C++ functions which is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the CUDA libraries to your MEX file. It looks like you're also using some of the `"cutil.h"` stuff from the CUDA SDK (such as `cutCheckCmdLineFlag`), so you'll need to link against not only the cudart library, but also cutil. I.e. you probably need to add something like

```
-Lc:\CUDA\lib -lcudart -lcuda -L<path-to-cutil.lib> -lcutil
```

to your MEX command-line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are converting from CUDA to MATLAB, then why are you still calling the CUDA functions?

> unresolved external symbol
>   **__imp__cutCheckCmdLineFlag**@12

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here. The file I'm trying to convert is a .cpp file that calls external CUDA functions to perform operations on an image. I want to retain that functionality in the MEX file so I'm calling those functions. I'm pretty inexperienced with both, though, so if this is a giant mistake, let me know.

Comment: @Harold Wellington Graves: CUDA is a runtime system.  If you're not running CUDA code, then how can you call the CUDA functions?  This would be like trying to write C++ code in a VB project.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. And knowing that gives me a few ideas on how to resolve the problems I've been having. Thanks for the help! I'm going to leave this open a bit longer just to see if anyone else has comments.

Comment: @Harold Wellington Graves:  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

High Performance Mark is suggesting, in his comment, to compile mexfiles using CUDA directly under Visual Studio. At the page

[Compiling CUDA mex files with Visual Studio](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/498)

it is described how the compile mexfiles using CUDA under Visual Studio. There is also a downloadable Visual Studio sample project.

The procedure has been tested for CUDA 5.0, Visual Studio 2010 and Matlab 2010a/2012b, but perhaps it could be of interest also to people using other versions of the above products.